# Angularjs: assign mouse over/leave events to a child element of li tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mouseevent, mouseover

I am trying to assign mouse over/leave events to a span tag (child) of li, but can't know how to do it.

HTML file:

```
<div ng-controller="SliderCtrl">
    <div class="left-panel">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="right-panel">
        <gh-visualization val="data"></gh-visualization>
        <div class="chart">             
            <svg class="chart"></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="chart in charts">
                    <div class="mark" style="background-color:{{colors[$index]}}"></div>
                    <div class="asset"><span ng-mouseenter="showTooltip({{$index}})" hover-element>{{chart.asset_class}}</span></div>
                    <div class="investment">{{chart.investment_fund}}</div>
                    <div class="weight">{{chart.weight}}</div>              
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngResource"]);
app.factory("Chart", function($resource) {
  ...
});

app.controller('SliderCtrl', function($scope, Chart) {
  ...
  $scope.showTooltip = function(index) {
    $scope.temp = index;
  }  
});

app.directive('ghVisualization', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      val: '=',
      charts: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {   
        ...
      scope.showTooltip = function(index) {
        var temp = index;
      }
    }
  }
});

app.directive('hoverElement', function () {    
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {     
      element.bind("mouseover", function(e){    
           element.addClass('unfill').removeClass('filled');
      });
      element.bind("mouseout", function(e){
           element.addClass('filled').removeClass('unfill');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Let me explain about my code:

**SliderCtrl** controller and **ghVisualization** directive already exist and what I am trying to do is assigning mouse over/leave events to the span child tag of li in order to do certain action.

So like you see, at first I add **ng-mouseenter="showTooltip({{$index}})"** to span and defined showTooltip function in controller(but not called, so) and directive. (also doesn't work)

That's why I created a new directive called **hoverElement** and assign it into span, but also doesn't work.

What is wrong with my code and how can I implement this correctly?
I am newbie in AngularJS and hope many helps from all of you.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a property of scope as a parameter to an event-handlign function (registered with `ng-_eventtype_`), you don't need the interpolation (`{{` `}}`).

```
ng-mouseenter="showTooltip($index)"
```

The `hoverElement` directive **[seems OK](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/FUm9F/)** though.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that your ng-mouseenter should look like this

```
ng-mouseenter="showTooltip($index)"
```

instead of this

```
ng-mouseenter="showTooltip({{$index}})"
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ScNB5HXdXlyuv6056MY0?p=preview)